# Find the distance between the points of two tangents along a circle

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, circles, tangent-line

I have the following problem: there is a circle with the $R = 5$ and center of the circle located on coordinate $(0, 0)$. I have two points $A(6, 8)$ and $B(-4, -6)$. From points, tangents to the circle were drawn. It is better illustrated as:

[image]

Let us denote points where tangents and circle intersect as $E, F, G, H$ (see the picture above for better the understandings). So we need to find the distance between E and F along the circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

\begin{align}
|OE|=|OF|=
R&=5
,\quad
|OA|=10
,\quad 
|OB|=2\sqrt{13}
,\quad
|AB|=2\sqrt{74}
,\\
\triangle AOE:\quad
|AE|&=5\sqrt3
,\\
\triangle BFO:\quad
|BF|&=3\sqrt3
.
\end{align}

\begin{align} 
\angle EOF&=\angle AOB-\angle AOE-\angle FOB
,
\end{align}

\begin{align} 
\angle AOB&=\arccos\frac{|OA|^2+|OB|^2-|AB|^2}{2\cdot|OA|\cdot|OB|}
=
\pi-\arccos(\tfrac{18}{65}\sqrt{13})
,\\
\angle AOE&=
\arccos\frac{|OE|}{|OA|}
=\tfrac\pi3
,\\
\angle FOB&=
\arccos\frac{|OF|}{|OB|}
=\arccos(\tfrac5{26}\sqrt{13})
,\\
\angle EOF&=
\tfrac{2\pi}3-\arccos(\tfrac{18}{65}\sqrt{13})
-\arccos(\tfrac5{26}\sqrt{13})
\approx 1.234262917
.
\end{align}

So, 
the distance between $E$ and $F$ along the circle,
that is, the length of the arc $FE$ is

\begin{align} 
R\cdot\angle EOF&=
5\cdot(\tfrac{2\pi}3-\arccos(\tfrac{18}{65}\sqrt{13})
-\arccos(\tfrac5{26}\sqrt{13}))
\approx 6.171314600
.
\end{align}

Expression for $\angle EOF$ can be simplified to
\begin{align} 
\angle EOF&=
\arccos\frac{18+2\sqrt3}{65}
,
\end{align}
hence by the cosine rule 
we can also find

\begin{align} 
|EF|&=\tfrac1{13}\sqrt{6110-260\sqrt3}
\approx 5.78698130
.
\end{align}

Comment: Very good, thank you!

Comment: @Yerassyl: Welcome to Math.SE!

Answer (score 0):

If we pick point $E$ for example, then we know that $EO \perp EA$. This means that $(\text{slope of EO})(\text{slope of EA})$ equals $-1$. If $E = (x, y)$, we have:

$$\frac{8-y}{6-x} \cdot \frac{y - 0}{x - 0} = -1$$

$E$ also lies on the circle, so:

$$x^2+y^2=5^2$$

which gives two possibilities for $(x,y)$, where one is $E$ and the other is point $G$.

You can repeat this same process to find $F$, after which you can just use the distance formula.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the chord of the circle $x^2+y^2=r^2$ passing through the two tangent points drawn from the external point $(x_1,y_1)$ is $x_1x+y_1y =r^2$. Then, the equations of the chords EG and FH are, respectively

$$6x+8y=25,\>\>\>\>\>-4x-6y=25$$

Substitute them into $x^2+y^2=25$ to obtain the points $E(\frac32+2\sqrt3, 2-\frac32\sqrt3)$ and $F(\frac{45}{26}\sqrt3-\frac{25}{13}, -\frac{75}{26}-\frac{15}{13}\sqrt3)$, which yields the distance

$$EF=\sqrt{\frac{10}{13}(47-2\sqrt3)}$$

Comment: Can you please clarify the moment when you found the equations of chords $EG$ and $FH$?